# How to print odd numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my code.  I can't get the odd numbers to print just the odd numbers and I don't know how to not print the []'s on the output.  can someone help?

```
size = 5

def get_numbers(num):
    numbers = []
    user_input = input('Enter {} integers:\n'.format(num))

    i = 0
    for token in user_input.split():
        number = int(token)     # Convert string input into integer
        numbers.append(number)  # Add to numbers list

        print(i, number)
        i += 1

    return numbers


def print_all_numbers(numbers):
    # Print numbers
    print('Numbers:', numbers)


def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            print('Odd numbers:', nums)


def print_negative_numbers(numbers):
    # Print all negative numbers
    for neg in numbers:
        if neg <= 0:
            print('Negative numbers:', nums)


nums = get_numbers(size)
print_all_numbers(nums)
print_odd_numbers(nums)
print_negative_numbers(nums)
```

Comment: What are you trying to print? Each individual odd number on its own line? Or a list of all the odd numbers?

Comment: if you want to print all odd numbers in one line then first you have to filter numbers and create list `nums` only with odd number (ie. using `nums.append(number)` inside `for`-loop)  - and later print this `nums` (after `for`-loop)

Comment: Declare a new variable odd_nums = '' and add new odd numbers to it, e.g. odd_nums = odd_nums + ',' + str(number)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print each individual odd number on its own line, just print `number`:

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            print('Odd numbers:', number)
print_odd_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Output:

```
Odd numbers: 1
Odd numbers: 3
Odd numbers: 5
```

If you want to print them like a normal list without the square brackets, you could use list-comprehension:

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    odd_numbers = [str(number) for number in numbers if number % 2 == 1]
    print('Odd numbers:', ', '.join(odd_numbers))
print_odd_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Output:

```
Odd numbers: 1, 3, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to filter numbers - ie. using `append()` inside `for`-loop, and later you can dispay this `nums`

```
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    # --- before loop ---
    nums = []

    # --- loop ---
    for number in numbers:
        if number % 2 == 1:
            nums.append(number)

    # --- after loop ---
    print('Odd numbers:', nums)
```

To display without `[]` you have to convert numbers to strings and create one string using `join`

```
    # --- after loop ---

    # convert numbers to strings
    nums = [str(s) for x in nums]

    # create single string
    nums_txt = ", ".join(nums)

    # display it
    print('Odd numbers:', nums_txt)
```

---

BTW: you can all this make shorter using `list comprehension` like in @richardec answer - but at start my version can be more readable for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`. In this case, `filter()` will take in a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that checks whether each element is odd and returns a new list that only contains the elements that pass this check (i.e. only the elements which are odd).

```py
def print_odd_numbers(numbers):
    odd_numbers = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, numbers))
    for number in odd_numbers:
        print('Odd number:', number)

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
print_odd_numbers(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#print odd numbers
n = int(input('Enter till number'))
list = [i for i in range(n)  if i%2 !=0]
print(*list)
```

here is the explanation
The first line takes input as a number till odd numbers will be printed
for i in range(n) crates numbers from 0 to n and pass to if condition which is checking for odd condition. if the condition is satisfied i will be placed in the list.
last line prints list

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.